# mySQL count functionality

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count all records from my 'jobs' table that have a 'completed' status, excluding any jobs that are either 'fix-it' or 'vacancy' job types. This is what I'm using, but I'm not sure if this is giving me the correct results:

```
SELECT id, client_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM jobs 
WHERE jobType != 'fix-it' AND jobType != 'vacancy' AND status = 'completed' 
GROUP by jobs.client_id
```

I then look at the result to see if I have two or more completed jobs under a given client.

Does this look correct?

Comment: Could you post a little example data? Your code looks OK, just wanted to test stuff.

Comment: If "jobType" is NULL, do you want to see those records?  Why do you select "id" in the query?  What do you think it is telling you?

Comment: Yes, i would want to see those records. Wouldn't they be included though, because I'm using != to filter? NULL would not equal either 'vacancy' or 'fix-it', and as such it would be included right?

As far as the 'id' goes, you're right, I don't need it.

Comment: Re: NULL, no.  `NULL != col` evaluates to NULL, not true or false.  Re: "id", it's not just not needed, it doesn't make sense, and I'd recommend using [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the two jobtype things with a single `NOT IN` clause, to make things a little more legible...

```
WHERE jobType NOT IN ('fix-it', 'vacancy') AND ...
```

otherwise it looks ok

Answer (score 0):

This works in SQL Server, not sure about MySql:

```
SELECT id, client_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM jobs 
WHERE jobType != 'fix-it' AND jobType != 'vacancy' AND status = 'completed' 
GROUP by jobs.client_id
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

Comment: it won't work. you'll get the "selecting non-aggregate fields not in a group by" error. SQL server's stupid like that.

Comment: I actually do that > 1 count check using PHP, so that's not a problem. I'm mainly concerned whether the above query would generate the intended results, given that I'm pretty new to using COUNT.

Comment: @Marc B's comment is very true, you'd have to add the id and client id to group by in SQL server

Comment: @Jeremy Unless you want to display all the results, I always try to filter in the query...

Comment: @MarcB You have it backwards. It's MySQL that is stupid here, by returning an indeterminate id.